# Plugin for Magento\Setup\Model\ConfigOptionsList::validate

Tags: plugin, setup, interceptor

Is it possible to make a plugin for `Magento\Setup\Model\ConfigOptionsList::validate()`?
This function checks the validity of connection to DB and since I am dynamically generating password for DB, I need to intercept the `$options` argument and pass my own password.
I tried doing it the normal way:

```
<type name="Magento\Setup\Model\ConfigOptionsList">
        <plugin name="vendor_dynamic_password_plugin" sortOrder="1" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\DynamicPasswordPlugin"/>
</type>
```

The plugin:

```
public function beforeValidate(ConfigOptionsList $subject, array $options, DeploymentConfig $deploymentConfig)
    {
        dd('it works!');
        return [$options, $deploymentConfig];
    }
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work. This will not even generate the interceptor. I know I could use the `--skip-db-validation` argument, but I don't want to bypass the internal DB validation.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the custom password using `--db-password` param.

Reference: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/advanced.html?lang=en

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I want to do. The DB password is dynamically generated by a custom module in M2, I just need to pass it to the options argument in the validate function.